# Could it cause any problem if I not reboot after a kernel upgrade?

Tags: linux, kernel, upgrade

I know there are solution for not rebooting after kernel update:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ksplice

But If Ksplice isn't installed, and the user doesn't reboots it's notebook after even several kernel updates (so notebook running for even months). Could there be a problem about it? (not counting that an update probably came because there was a bugfix or security fix)

Comment: Are you upgrading a kernel you are currently using? If so, there might be issues. If you aren't currently using it, then no. And I'm not sure what issues you would run into. I think I've done it and not noticed anything but ymmv.

Comment: To answer your Q, yes there could be a problem if there was a patch to the Kernel that impacted the overall use of the system or dealt with a security vulnerability.

Comment: @slm I disagree that this question is primarily opinion-based — inasmuch as it is subjective, it falls pretty hard on the “good subjective” side, since it invites sharing facts and experiences (what can go wrong).

Comment: An important thing in practice, that hasn't been mentioned in answers so far, is that unless this is an upgrade with a fully compatible ABI (which might be the case for a security upgrade, but is not the case for most upgrades, in particular not for upgrades where the x.y.z version has changed), you won't be able to load modules from the new version into a running kernel with the old version. So if you keep running a kernel, you should keep the corresponding package around.

Comment: @Gilles - fair enough, Q's reopened, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't affect the kernel itself (besides not taking advantage of the update).

However, some newly installed programs might rely on newer kernel features.

Also, if you run a program that relies on loading a kernel module then you may find that that module is no longer installed, and newly installed modules won't load in the old kernel.

Basically, if there is a problem, you'll see it. Otherwise you're fine.

Answer (score 3):

No, not really. The new kernels simply won't be used.

Comment: hey, I like your avatar :)

Comment: It's the OpenBSD mascot.

Comment: yepp, I know :) http://www.openbsdfoundation.org/

Answer (score 0):

Most people install updates to fix bugs, apply security updates and to get new features.

As you remarked: unless you use technology like Ksplice the Linux system needs to be rebooted for an update to kernel to take effect, simply installing a new kernel is not enough.

So if you do not reboot you might as well not have installed the kernel update for all the effect it has, as you can  still run into the bug that was fixed by that kernel update, you may still fall victim to an exploit using an security hole that was fixed and you can't use the new features.